# Django not running view, 404

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

so I think I had this figured it out but for some reason I cannot find what I'm doing wrong when this seems so simple. I have a button that once pressed, calls a view and passes along an id.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^home', 'home', name='home'),
    url(r'^create_modbus_device', 'create_modbus_device', name='create_modbus_device'),

    url(r'^create_modbus', 'create_modbus_view', name='create_modbus_view'),
    url(r'^create_bacnet', 'create_bacnet_view', name='create_bacnet_view'),

    url(r'^add_device/(?P<form_count>\d{4})', 'add_device', name='add_device'),


)
```

button

```
<a href="/add_device/1"></a>
```

view

```
def add_device(request, form_count=0):
    return ..
```

however django is returning 404 and never calls my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `\d{4}` matches four digits exactly. Your url `/add_device/1` has only one digit, so it doesn't match.

If you want to match one or more digits, change the url pattern to

```
url(r'^add_device/(?P<form_count>\d+)', 'add_device', name='add_device'),
```